# For until square root

Tags: scala

In Scala, I want to write the equivalent of the following C++ code:

```
for(int i = 1 ; i * i < n ; i++)
```

So far I did this, but it looks ugly and I think it goes up until n:

```
for(i <- 1 to n 
            if(i * i < n))
```

Is there a nicer way of writing this code?

Comment: Why cant we just run the loop from 1 to log(n) base 2 ? We are doing a multiply operation at every step in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Not nicer but different approach

## Using a stream

```
(1 to n).toStream map (i => i * i) takeWhile (_ < n)
```

## Example for n = 100

```
scala> val res = (1 to 100).toStream map(i => i * i) takeWhile (_ < 100)
res: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> res.toList
res16: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81)
```

## Explanation

A `Stream` allows to request values on demand, i.e. lazy evaluation. So the function that is mapped will only be applied when the next value is requested.

Comment: We are multiplying `i` even when `i*i` was greater than n. This is even lesser performant than the code written by OP running close to 3n times.

Comment: @Sohaib That code will not multiply `i` when `i * i` is greater than `n`. Notice that it is a stream. A stream is lazy.

Comment: Will extend with explanation so that nobody suffers the same mistake ;)

Comment: @AndreasNeumann My bad. But still no need of multiple multiply operations when we can simply compare it with the sqrt of the number perhaps.

Comment: Keep in mind that the stream will be kept in memory for the whole iteration, while in reality you don't need the indices of previous iterations. Also you don't need to use `map` when all you want is to write a side-effecting loop. Just use `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have might not be the nicest but it might be the most efficient, everything else is internally more complicated, so it might have some overhead. (In most situations not a notable overhead though, and it might be optimized very well.)

I would not go for the solution using Streams suggested in an other answer. While streams are computed lazily, they do cache the computed results, which is not required in this case and might take a lot of memory if the range iterated over is large. Instead I would use an Iterator. Operations on Iterators are typically lazy as well and do not cache anything.

If you need this more often, you could add an other "operator" using an implicit class like this:

```scala
implicit class UntilHelper(start: Int) {
    def aslong(cond: Int => Boolean) =
        Iterator.from(start).takeWhile(cond)
}
```

Your loop then looks like this:

```
for(i <- 1 aslong (Math.pow(_, 2) < 1000)) {
    println(i)
}
```

From a quick micro-benchmark it looks like this is about 3 times faster than the stream solution and a little bit slower than a simple while loop. These things are however notoriously hard to measure without any context.

### Remark on computing squares

A nice way of computing a sequence of Squares is by adding the difference between squares. This can be done using the scanLeft method on a Stream or an Iterator.

```
val itr = Iterator.from(1).scanLeft(1)((a,b)=>a + 2*b+1)
println(itr.take(10).toList)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, declare a function to generate a lazy stream of squares:

```
def squares(i: Int = 1): Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(i * i, squares(i + 1))
```

then use takeWhile to get the value when i * i is smaller than n. For example:

```
scala> squares().takeWhile(_ < 50).foreach(println)
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
```